# If a developer develops me an iPhone app using their developer account and certificates etc?

Tags: iphone, ios

Quick one, if a developer develops me an iPhone app using their developer account and certificates etc?  and their provisioning profile etc.. and then sends me the completed zipped .app file to upload to my developer account, will it get accepted?

Comment: Sounds like a question that's better suited to an iPhone developer community. It's definitely not on topic for stackoverflow, take a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit off topic, but no.  They would need to sign the app file with YOUR certificate for you to be able to submit it to the store via your account.

Answer (score 0):

No. Certificates and accounts must match.